# Tail Recursive Percolate

Tags: java, data-structures, heap, tail-recursion, heapsort

```
public void insert(int number) {
    heapArr.add(number);
    percolateUp(this.heapArr.size()-1);
}


public void percolateUp(int key) {
    if (getParent(key) >=0 && heapArr.get(getParent(key)) < heapArr.get(key)) {
        int temp = heapArr.get(getParent(key));
        heapArr.set(getParent(key), heapArr.get(key));
        heapArr.set(key, temp);
        percolateUp(getParent(key));
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

I am trying to wrap my head around tail recursion, and as far as I learned, some compilers can tell whether you have a tail recursive function and not create any extra stack frames. In my case above, I am trying to figure out whether the recursive percolate is tail recursive. It's not necessarily waiting for a return from the function so would a compiler recognize this as tail recursive?

Comment: would be nice to label the language, is this java?

Comment: @volk Well, `javac` (the compiler you most likely refer to) does not do any static tail-call analysis or optimization... that would more likely be something the JVM would do with dynamic analysis at runtime :-) AFAIK HotSpot does not do it, but the [Da Vinci Machine](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/mlvm/) project appears to have [delved into the topic](https://blogs.oracle.com/jrose/entry/tail_calls_in_the_vm).

Comment: @volk it is indeed tail recursion though... not that it matters much :-p

Comment: @veer, thanks a lot. that was very informative.